# Triggering an action when a specific volume is connected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automounting

I have a USB key that contains my keepass2 password database and I'd like to perform some actions when it is plugged into my computer, namely:

- Auto-mount it to some specific location
- When the mounting is done properly, launching keepass2 on the password database file

Simple tasks I guess, but I can't find how to do that.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and it auto-mounts the device as a "media usb-key" and tries to open the images on it (even though there are none).

What is the best way to do that and to disable the ubuntu auto-mounting (so it doesn't conflict) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a new device appears, [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) is notified. It normally creates a device file under `/dev` based on built-in rules¹. You can override these rules to change the device file location or run an arbitrary program. Here is a sample such udev rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodine", ATTRS{serial}=="123456789", NAME="keepass/s%n", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/keepass-drive-inserted /dev/%k%n"
```

The `NAME=` directive changes the location of the device file, I included it for illustration purposes but it is probably not useful for your use case. The `ATTRS` rules identify the device; run `udevinfo -a -n /dev/sdz` when the drive is available as `/dev/sdz` to see what attributes it has. Beware that you can only use `ATTRS` rules from a single section of the `udevinfo` input (in addition, you can use `ATTR` rules from the initial section). See [Understand output of `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45791/understand-output-of-udevadm-info-a-n-dev-sdb) for more background. This rule goes into a file called something like `/etc/udev/rules.d/local-storage-keypass.rules`.

Put the commands you want to run in the script given in the `RUN` directive. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if [ -d /media/keypass-drive ]; then
  [ "$(df -P /media/keypass-drive | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')" = "$(df -P /media | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')" ]
else
  mkdir /media/keypass-drive
fi
mount "$1" /media/keypass-drive
su ereon -c 'keypass2' &
```

If you're having trouble running a GUI program from a script triggered from udev, see [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root)

¹  <sub>Not on modern systems where `/dev` is on udevtmpfs.</sub>

Comment: Important note on this: When writing rules using the info from `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdX`, you cannot match based on multiple ancestors. You can only match based on data from the device itself, and a single ancestor. This is covered in `man 7 udev`, but is a small comment easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this would be writing your own udev rule(s) for this device. Unfortunately I can't give any tips on how to do this as I've never done so. So unless someone else has a more detailed answer, google for 'udev rules' and look in /lib/udev for examples. Your custom udev rules should go in /etc/udev/rules.d

Comment: Thanks for the info. This will at least make my searches more efficient.