# go-mptfs and mounting smartphone devices under /dev/sdx

Tags: mount, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy J5 which has micro-usb (as most modern Samsung smartphones go) which gets mounted under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=someaddress` .

While I'm able to use it like that but it is very inconvenient as all other usb devices live /media/shirish/XXX . I read [How to force a device to be mounted as Mass Media Storage (MMS) rather than Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176140/how-to-force-a-device-to-be-mounted-as-mass-media-storage-mms-rather-than-medi) .

I installed go-mtpfs in the hopes that it will make the phone and the micro-usb card mount under /dev/sdx and use the naming function such as /media/shirish/xxx but the only way that would work is to write udev hand-written rules which would probably require maintenance as and when upstream (systemd and hence udev) changes how it function .

For something like this can anybody help me with a shell-script which might work for sometime. Also, does anybody if anything is cooking in relation to mtp:// and MMS so it is more easier to work with in the long-run.